# How to get all lines from a file after the last empty line?

Tags: bash

Having a file like foo.txt with content

```
1
2

3

4
5
```

How do i get the lines starting with 4 and 5 out of it (everything after last empty line), assuming the amount of lines can be different?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @daniu That would match from the *first* empty line to the end of the file.

Comment: What should be output for files that have no blank lines?  What counts as a "blank line" (must it have nothing at all on it, or could it have whitespace characters on it)?  If the last line of the file is unterminated, do you want it terminated in the output, or not?

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

A modification of [oliv's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54367325/8656552) that allows records with or without CRLF endings, and accommodates multiple consecutive blank lines:

```
awk -v RS='(\r*\n){2,}' 'END{sub(/(\r*\n*)*$/,""); printf "%s\n",$0}' file
```

## Update

My original solution had serious bugs in it.

The `N` adds the next line to the pattern space without testing it first, which includes *empty* lines, and consumes the line so that the test for empty lines gets bypassed.

It also *exits* if it fails to successfully read, so it only successfully printed on the original example test file because the last blank line had *exactly* two lines after it, so after the `N` the `$p` evaluated and worked...

For those attempting to figure out what's actually happening in your `sed` programs, I highly recommend the `--debug` option.

With the original file:

```
$: printf 'a\n\nb\n\nc\nd\n' > file
$: sed -n '/^\s*$/{g;D;}; N; $p;' file # it's a lie - pure luck!
c
d
```

but move the blank line *anywhere* else, or let there be none...

```
$: printf 'a\nb\nc\n\nd\n' > file
$: sed -n '/^\s*$/{g;D;}; N; $p;' file # oops!
$: printf 'a\n\nb\nc\nd\n' > file
$: sed -n '/^\s*$/{g;D;}; N; $p;' file # fail again
$: printf 'a\nb\nc\n' > file           
$: sed -n '/^\s*$/{g;D;}; N; $p;' file # and again
$: printf 'a\nb\nc\nd\n' > file
$: sed -n '/^\s*$/{g;D;}; N; $p;' file # what the hell??
c
d
```

Let's look at these a little closer...

With the original file, *BOTH* blank lines were eaten by `N` and never even seen by the pattern scan. Lines a, b, and c were scanned but didn't match. Line d was appended to c by the `N`, *making* the `$` check for last line *true*, so the pattern buffer was printed, and then there were no more lines to read, so the program exited with a success code. Pure blind luck.

```
$: printf 'a\n\nb\n\nc\nd\n'|sed -n '/^$/{g;D;};N;$p' --debug
SED PROGRAM:
  /^$/ {
    g
    D
  }
  N
  $ p
INPUT:   'STDIN' line 1
PATTERN: a
COMMAND: /^$/ {
COMMAND: }
COMMAND: N
PATTERN: a\n
COMMAND: $ p
END-OF-CYCLE:
INPUT:   'STDIN' line 3
PATTERN: b
COMMAND: /^$/ {
COMMAND: }
COMMAND: N
PATTERN: b\n
COMMAND: $ p
END-OF-CYCLE:
INPUT:   'STDIN' line 5
PATTERN: c
COMMAND: /^$/ {
COMMAND: }
COMMAND: N
PATTERN: c\nd
COMMAND: $ p
c
d
END-OF-CYCLE:
```

In fact, this old code will *always* print either the last two lines, or nothing at all.

Every normal read overwrites the pattern buffer with the new line, so all previous data is lost. If that happens on the last line, the `N` can't read another, *and exits*.

```
$: printf 'a\nb\nc\n'|sed -n '/^$/{g;D;};N;$p' --debug
SED PROGRAM:
  /^$/ {
    g
    D
  }
  N
  $ p
INPUT:   'STDIN' line 1
PATTERN: a
COMMAND: /^$/ {
COMMAND: }
COMMAND: N
PATTERN: a\nb
COMMAND: $ p
END-OF-CYCLE:
INPUT:   'STDIN' line 3
PATTERN: c
COMMAND: /^$/ {
COMMAND: }
COMMAND: N
END-OF-CYCLE:
```

If it happens on the *next* to the last line, the `N` appends the last line, which *makes* the current line the last line, so the `$p` triggers, prints them both (which is what happened above), and lets the program try - and fail - to read another line, and then exit.

```
$: printf 'a\nb\n'|sed -n '/^$/{g;D;};N;$p' --debug
SED PROGRAM:
  /^$/ {
    g
    D
  }
  N
  $ p
INPUT:   'STDIN' line 1
PATTERN: a
COMMAND: /^$/ {
COMMAND: }
COMMAND: N
PATTERN: a\nb
COMMAND: $ p
a
b
END-OF-CYCLE:
```

The slightly more complicated but corrected version -
note that carriage returns don't matter.

```
$: for f in 'a\nb\n' 'a\nb\nc\n' 'a\n\nb\n' 'a\nb\nc\n\nd\ne\nf\n'
>  do echo "[${f@Q}]"; printf "$f"|sed -n '/^\s*$/{x;d};H;${x;s/^\n*//;p};'
>  done
['a\nb\n']
a
b
['a\nb\nc\n']
a
b
c
['a\n\nb\n']
b
['a\nb\nc\n\nd\ne\nf\n']
d
e
f
```

BTW, the same logic is cleaner and easier to read in `awk`, and doesn't require knocking off the extraneous leading newline before you print it.

```
$: for f in 'a\nb\n' 'a\nb\nc\n' 'a\n\nb\n' 'a\nb\nc\n\nd\ne\nf\n'
>  do echo "[${f@Q}]"; printf "$f"|awk '{out=out$0RS}/^\s*$/{out=""}END{printf "%s",out}'; done
['a\nb\n']
a
b
['a\nb\nc\n']
a
b
c
['a\n\nb\n']
b
['a\nb\nc\n\nd\ne\nf\n']
d
e
f
```

Also, I assume this format is for INI files or some such, so the straightforward `awk` is probably best... but if a file has big sections between blank lines, this will grab enough memory to hold it. You *could* have `awk` make one pass to find the last blank line and another to print from there on by passing the file argument twice:

```
$: for f in 'a\nb\n' 'a\nb\nc\n' 'a\n\nb\n' 'a\nb\nc\n\nd\ne\nf\n'
>  do echo "[${f@Q}]"; printf "$f" > file;
>     awk 'NR==FNR && /^\s*$/ { start=NR } NR>FNR && FNR>start' file file
>  done
['a\nb\n']
a
b
['a\nb\nc\n']
a
b
c
['a\n\nb\n']
b
['a\nb\nc\n\nd\ne\nf\n']
d
e
f
```

...but [oliv's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54367325/8656552) is so much better.

Just tell `awk` that the record separator is two or more consecutive newlines, and only print the last record.

You can even tell it to allow (or require) carriage returns, and allow more than one blank line to count as a single separator.

```
$: for f in 'a\nb\n' 'a\nb\nc\n' 'a\n\nb\n' 'a\nb\nc\n\nd\ne\nf\n' 'a\n\nb\n\n' 'a\n\r\n\n\r\nb\nc\r\nd\n\n\n'
>  do echo "[${f@Q}]"
>     printf "$f"|awk -v RS='(\r*\n){2,}' 'END{printf "%s\n",$0}';
>  done
['a\nb\n']
a
b

['a\nb\nc\n']
a
b
c

['a\n\nb\n']
b

['a\nb\nc\n\nd\ne\nf\n']
d
e
f

['a\n\nb\n\n']
b
['a\n\r\n\n\r\nb\nc\r\nd\n\n\n']
b
c
d
```

Note that this does include any single newline at the end of a record, but strips multiples, so all but my 5th example have a blank line *after*... You can fix that by stripping any line endings explicitly before printing.

```
$: for f in 'a\nb\n' 'a\nb\nc\n' 'a\n\nb\n' 'a\nb\nc\n\nd\ne\nf\n' 'a\n\nb\n\n' 'a\n\r\n\n\r\nb\nc\r\nd\n\n\n'
> do echo "[${f@Q}]"; printf "$f"|awk -v RS='(\r*\n){2,}' 'END{sub(/(\r*\n*)*$/,""); printf "%s\n",$0}'; done
['a\nb\n']
a
b
['a\nb\nc\n']
a
b
c
['a\n\nb\n']
b
['a\nb\nc\n\nd\ne\nf\n']
d
e
f
['a\n\nb\n\n']
b
['a\n\r\n\n\r\nb\nc\r\nd\n\n\n']
b
c
d
```

Comment: for those empty line with pattern `^\s*$`, using `sed -n '/^\s*$/{g;D;}; N; $p;'`.

Comment: one more question, how to handle the file with `CRLF`, i.e.: `$ echo -e '1\r\n\r\n2\r\n3\r\n4\r' | sed -n '/^\s*\r$/{g;D;}; N; $p;'` not working, but using `tac` works ( `$ echo -e '1\r\n\r\n2\r\n3\r\n4\r' | tac | awk '/^\s*\r$/{exit}1' | tac` )

Comment: @Maslo: In regular expressions, `\s` matches "whitespace" characters, which include carriage returns. `/^\s*$/` already works with or without them. `/^\s*\r$/` requires them, if that's what you want, but it also forces a little backtracking.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU `awk`:

```
awk -v RS='\n\n' 'END{printf "%s",$0}' file
```

`RS` is the record separator set to empty line.

The `END` statement prints the last record.

Comment: However, if the last line of the file is blank, this will print the last preceding block with no line terminator...

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the file, print everything up to the first blank line, reverse it again.

```
$ tac foo.txt | awk '/^$/{exit}1' | tac
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 tail +$(($(grep -nE ^$ test.txt | tail -n1 | sed  -e 's/://g')+1)) test.txt
```

- grep your input file for empty lines.
- get last line with tail => `5:`
- remove unnecessary `:`
- add `1` to `5` => `6`
- tail starting from `6`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with sed :

```
sed -n ':A;$bB;/^$/{x;s/.*//;x};H;n;bA;:B;H;x;s/^..//;p' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed:

```
sed ':a;/$/{N;s/.*\n\n//;ba;}' file
```